# How to open an android app via intent filter?

Tags: android, filter, android-intent, send

I am trying to open a file with my app and to receive a file via the SEND intent.
I've tried several filters in the manifest file but could not get it to be displayed anywhere.
How is this done?

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="file" />
                    <data android:mimeType="*" /> 
<data android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: try setting the mimeType to "*/*"

Comment: great, thank you! but how can I SEND a file to my app and how do I receive it? the broadcast receiver is already used by a widget.

Comment: using: getIntent(), it's that simple! But when opened with SEND the intent is empty?!